# How to set up npm live-server for Node.js Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm-live-server

I've just getting into programming and I was told to try and use node.js for JavaScript. I've been watching this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGdd9qNwQdQ&list=PLoYCgNOIyGACTDHuZtn0qoBdpzV9c327V) and he seems to have a tab open called local host where he is allowed to code. I have no idea how to do this. I guess hes using a live-server? I've tried going online [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server) to set it up but to no avail. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: node.js can use localhost, aka `127.0.0.1` or (your IP here). node comes with the http module (require("http")), which is all the server you need. look at the node home page.

Comment: Not really a programming question, the Javascript tag can be removed

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the video he explains how to tell your browser to show that javascript console where you can interactively play around - its F12 or ctrl+shift+J  on ubuntu   ...   you can [download Node.js here](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Once you have installed Node.js then from a linux/OSX terminal type :

```
node
```

which launches node in an interactive javascript execution command line mode ... Behind the facade of chrome browser or node is the V8 engine which is actually where javascript gets compiled and executed